# How can I automatically restart my Heroku app when there's a server error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a Rails 4.2 app running on Heroku. Occasionally there is an issue that causes most incoming requests to get a server error. For example, there could be a memory leak or a max database connection issue.  How can I setup a script or service to automatically restart the server when it detects errors?

I think this service could ping the app every few minutes and if it detects an error, it should confirm there's really a problem and then run `heroku restart`. How could this be set up?

Answer (score 0):

After Googling this topic, I came across Neptune.io, which seems to provide a useful service for this task.